# Background image in view controller result in memory increase + UIColor colorWithPatternImage

Tags: image, memory, background, memory-leaks, uicolor

I tried 2 different methods of creating a background image for a view controller.

I have researched this before and came to the conclusion that for good memory practice you should use this method:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"controllerBackground" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@""];

[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]]];
```

When using the other method:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"controllerBackground.png"]]];
```

This is not as efficient as using the imageWithContentsOfFile:path method.

However when testing both these methods using the performance tools "leak" monitor, I observed a very unusual thing happening.

While using the `imageWithContentsOfFile:path` method, the problem was that when going back and forth within a navigation controller loading the view controller, the memory would keep increasing within the vicinity of approximately 1mb every time the view controller loads.

This problem is also only observed in the new iOS 4.1 and 4. It does not seem to happen in the iOS 3.0 or 3.2.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fix that worked for me.

```
UImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"name.png"];
self.view.layer.contents = (id) image.CGImage;
```

You have to import QuartzCore, now i don't have 2MB memory increase every time i go that view.

Comment: I'm very new to this - where do I put this code? In the ViewController.h file? Or .m? And where in those files does the code go? I've tried everywhere and keep getting errors.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken this will not create a pattern, just set your image as a background for the view.

Comment: @Alfo ofcourse in the .m file. i did it in the viewDidLoad method of my viewController. Regarding errors, did you add the QuartzCore framework and added them to the class ?

Answer (score 0):

Allan, I faced the same problem and found that colorWithPatternImage and initWithPatternImage is taking large memory than expected. Here is a link which explains the same.

http://www.cocoabyss.com/coding-practice/colorwithpatternimage-abusive-memory-usage/

Better to avoid both methods for background images.

Comment: colorWithPatternImage takes a lot of memory because it has to load the image into RAM. UIImageView doesn't do this, but adds it to texture memory instead. colorWithPatternImage is meant to be used with small images (like 10x10px) to be repeated, and for this purpose it does its job very well.